# Declare a type with attribute and text, limited by pattern

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to declare next type:

```
<partCode negation="true|false">\*|[0-9]{1,9}</name>
```

with boolean attribute, and text-only content, limited by a pattern (`*` or a number).

I have next XSD so far:

```
<xs:complexType name="partCode">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\*|[0-9]{1,9}" />
        </xs:restriction>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string"> <-- error
            <xs:attribute name="negation" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

But it contains an error:

> The 'extension' element already exists in the content model

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:complexType name="PartCodeValue">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="negation" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="PartCode">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="PartCodeValue">
            <xs:pattern value="\*|[0-9]{1,9}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict and extend in the same step. First define a restriction of `xs:string` that satisfies the pattern; then define an extension of this that adds the attribute.

Comment: Could you please bring an example, and will glad to accept it.